# Class "Stripe\Stripe" not found in codeigniter 4

Tags: php, stripe-payments, codeigniter-4

i downloaded stripe php library by using Composer with this command

> composer require stripe/stripe-php

---

then i added this in my app/config/autoload.php

```
public $psr4 = [        APP_NAMESPACE => APPPATH, // For custom app
     namespace      'Config'      => APPPATH . 'Config',        
'Stripe' =>> ROOTPATH . 'vendor/stripe/stripe-php/init.php' // added here   ];
```

---

then in controller i added this code but it giving me error Stripe/Stripe Not found

```
use Stripe; 
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(STRIPE_SECRET);    

         $paymentData = \Stripe\Charge::create ([
                 "amount" => $this->request->getPost('grandtotal'),
                 "currency" => "GBP",
                 "source" => $_REQUEST["stripeToken"],
                 "description" => "Test payment via Stripe From Rahul" 
         ]);
         $paymentData = array('success' => true, 'data'=> $stripe);
        
         echo '<pre>' , var_dump($paymentData) , '</pre>';
```

---

i followed one tutorial but it giving me this error, please help me

Comment: Can you provide the structure of your CI controller? Also, you don't need to import the path of stripe, it is automatically available via composer.

Comment: @DhavalChheda sir this is my Controller structure app/Controller/pays/stripecontroller.php

Comment: i left composer method then followed direct download method and its worked for me. i followed this tutorial https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/stripe-payment-gateway-integration-in-codeigniter-exampleexample.html

Answer (score 0):

> You could use autoloader to actually include the Stripe classes...
>
> require_once('vendor/autoload.php');